# Set value into merged cells from regular cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set value from regular cell into merged cells. Currently when I'm trying to set values into merged values it only sets first value and ignores rest of them.

```
function generate(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Newsletters');
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = s1.getLastRow()*4;


for (var i = 5; i <= lastRow; i++) { // Start from row 5
  var country_src = s1.getRange([i], 10).getValues(); //Country
  var languages_src = s1.getRange([i], 9).getValues(); //Languages

  var country = s2.getRange([i], 1); //Country
  var languages = s2.getRange([i], 2); //Languages

      if (languages_src != '') {
        languages.setValue(languages_src);
        country.setValue(country_src);
      }     
  }

}
```

I want to go from this:
[image]
To this:
[image]

Currently it gives me this:

[image]

Comment: So you want each row of `_src` to become a merged cell of 4 rows in the target with the same color and centered vertically and horizontally?  You show target as a merged cell but with the `value` in the lower left corner.  How did it get merged, manually?  Your script doesn't show how that was achieved.

Comment: Merged cells only hold one value in the upper left cell all other values are destroyed which range was merged.  I'd recommend not to merge cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of producing the results you want.  I created a spreadsheet similar to your source.

[image]

Then I create a script to take the source and produce the results.  With this script I get the `values` and `colors` of each cell.  Then I create a `results` array filled in.  Note that for each row of source there has to be 4 rows or results.

**Code.gs**

```
function createMergedCells() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let range = sheet.getDataRange(); // no headers
    let values = range.getValues();
    let colors = range.getFontColors();
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
    let i = 1;
    let results = [];
    values.forEach( (row,index) => {
        if( row[0] !== "" ) {
          range = sheet.getRange(i,1,4,1)
          range.mergeVertically();
          range.setFontColor(colors[index][0]);
          range = sheet.getRange(i,2,4,1)
          range.mergeVertically();
          range.setFontColor(colors[index][1]);
          i = i + 4;
          results.push([row[0],row[1]]);
          results.push(["",""]);
          results.push(["",""]);
          results.push(["",""]);
        }
      }
    );
    range = sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,2);
    range.setValues(results);
    range.setVerticalAlignment("middle");
    range.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```